# eslint dependency conflicts in VueJS3 app

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, eslint

I have just started to build my first Vue3JS app and am trying to deploy the app on Netlify. I have run into some dependency issues trying to publish, and decided to try and upgrade the app before publishing. I then run into dependency issues in my local machine related to eslint. The following is returned to the terminal:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: portfolio@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: eslint-plugin-vue@8.7.1
npm ERR! node_modules/eslint-plugin-vue
npm ERR!   dev eslint-plugin-vue@"^8.0.3" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer eslint-plugin-vue@"^7.0.0" from @vue/eslint-config-standard@6.1.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@vue/eslint-config-standard
npm ERR!   dev @vue/eslint-config-standard@"^6.1.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

My `package.json` file is as follows:

```
{
  "name": "portfolio",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.8.3",
    "vue": "^3.2.13",
    "vue-router": "^4.0.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.16",
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.12.16",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-standard": "^6.1.0",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.25.3",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^11.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^5.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^8.0.3"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/vue3-essential",
      "@vue/standard"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "@babel/eslint-parser"
    },
    "rules": {}
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not dead",
    "not ie 11"
  ]
}
```

Anyone know any fixes?

Comment: Make package versions match in some way, you can upgrade `@vue/eslint-config-standard` or downgrade eslint-plugin-vue

Comment: Or you can create `.npmrc` file in your project with the content `legacy-peer-deps=true`, delete `node_modules` and run `npm install`

Comment: [You should not *force* a tag into your title.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) Because the tags appear below the question and tags are indexed by search engines along with the content of your question, you can trust that other people will be able to find your question based on tags they follow or search for.